# Windows boot error 0xc00000e & 0xc00000f

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub

I was running Linux Mint 18.1 and Windows 10. The grub loader was on an hdd with Linux, and Windows 10 was installed on an SSD.
When I went to boot I got a winload.exe 0xc00000e error.
After running `bootrec /fixmbr and /fixboot`
from an install disc it showed I did not have a windows install.
I tried the instructions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/pc-needs-to-be-repaired-file/5db06fb1-d8cc-47e0-b801-e5e341983e1a) and [Vijays suggestion here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/total-identified-windows-installations-0/52359f87-de4a-41dc-b0c3-cc275e1d9fbf)
but now I get a new error message: 0xc000000f
and grub looks like it’s been overwritten.
Any suggestions on how to get both my machines back?

Answer (score 0):

General suggestion:

If you have two disks in your computer remove one disk, say Linux disk, 
then install or repair Windows 10 when there is only one disk (with Windows) attached.

Then repeat the exercise removing Windows disk and attaching only Linux disk.

After that you can attach both disks and select which disk to boot using firmware  F12 key.

If you want GRUB (Linux loader) to boot both OS with a boot menu selection you have to rerun GRUB installation/reinstallation. This is the easiest way for dual-booting Linux and Windows.

Note:

To avoid boot problems both OS have to use UEFI booting(and GPT style disks) or both systems have to use BIOS booting(an MBR style disks).